# How to parse the brackets in Java?

Tags: java, parsing, stack, brackets

I need to write method which takes expression like this: **1 + 2 ) * 3 - 4 ) * 5 - 6 ) ) )**, and then to output String result like this **( ( 1 + 2 ) * ( ( 3 - 4 ) * ( 5 - 6 ) ) )**.

Sorry for my english, it's not my native language.

I used stack in this problem. I know how to check the correctness of the expression:

```
public boolean isParse(String str)
{
    Stack<Character> s = new Stack<Character>();
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = str.charAt(i);

        if(c == '{')
            s.push(c);
        else if(c == '[')
            s.push(c);
        else if(c == '(')
            s.push(c);
        else if(c == '}')
        {   if(s.isEmpty())
                return false;
            else if(s.pop() == '{')
            {

            }
            else
                return false;
        }
        else if(c == ']')
        {
            if(s.isEmpty())
                return false;
            else if(s.pop() == '[')
            {

            }
            else
                return false;
        }
        else if(c == ')')
        {
            if(s.isEmpty())
                return false;
            else if(s.pop() == '(')
            {

            }
            else
                return false;
        }
    }

    return s.isEmpty();
}
```

But I don't know how to fix this expression, as in the example above

Comment: Is there a rule to derive the result from the input?

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far?

Comment: @JasonZ m first thought too.  That or a tree.

Comment: If you are saying you used `Stack`, then show some of your code.

Comment: So, you wish to parse an expression which is broken and fix it? How exactly? The fix could have many possible solutions different from the one you provided...(e.g. `((1+2) * ((3 - 4) * (5-6)))`)

Comment: @radoh Yes I need to get the output result like this example ((1+2) * ((3 - 4) * (5-6))))

Comment: Oops, I actually generated the same example you did :D. But there could be different possible solutions, what is the **rule**? E.g. `(((((1+2) * 3 - 4) * 5-6)))`

Comment: @radoh The task is in the original: 
Write a program that takes from standard input an expression without left parentheses and prints the equivalent infix expression with parentheses inserted missing. For example, for the input data 1 + 2 ) * 3 - 4 ) * 5 - 6 ) ) ) => ( ( 1 + 2 ) * ( ( 3 - 4 ) * ( 5 - 6 ) ) )

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
static String complementLeftParen(String s) {
    Deque<String> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
        char ch = s.charAt(i);
        switch (ch) {
            case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
            case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
                if (!stack.isEmpty() && Character.isDigit(stack.peek().charAt(0)))
                    stack.push(stack.pop() + ch);
                else 
                    stack.push(Character.toString(ch));
                break;
            case '+': case '-': case '*': case '/':
                stack.push(Character.toString(ch));
                break;
            case ')':
                String right = stack.pop();
                String operator = stack.pop();
                String left = stack.pop();
                stack.push(String.format("( %s %s %s )", left, operator, right));
                break;
            case ' ': case '\t':
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown char: " + ch);
        }
    }
    if (stack.size() != 1)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid input: " + s);
    return stack.pop();
}
```

Sample result

```
String s ="1 + 2 ) * 3 - 4 ) * 5 - 6 ) ) )";
System.out.println(complementLeftParen(s));
// -> ( ( 1 + 2 ) * ( ( 3 - 4 ) * ( 5 - 6 ) ) )
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The method works correctly, as I need. :)

Comment: @komax93 dont just say thank you. accept the answer and upvote it.